# Keep login/logout link behaviour in menu with custom authentication system

Tags: php, wordpress

I have develop a custom authentication system for the private part of our website which is using WordPress (creating a `template` and putting all the PHP code in it). It works great but I would like to add a link for this custom login page to the top menu so that when a user is not logged in it displays "login" and when he is, "logout". We already have this behavior but the login link points to the classic login page (which by the way we need to keep working for administration purpose, but not directly accessible from the menu).

Note: Theme my login and Better WP security plugins are used with WordPress 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done what I needed with inspiration from here: http://teleogistic.net/2013/02/dynamically-add-items-to-a-wp_nav_menu-list/ in case it could help someone.